# Render all json objects?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I trying to render all objects names from my json file /api/tables.json into ? `<li>there</li>`'s

```
var Table = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    name: 'table',
    id: 1
}
});

var Tables = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Table,
url: 'api/table.json'
});

var TablesView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#mydiv',

template: _.template($("#table-template").html()),

initialize : function() {
  this.coll = new Tables()
  this.listenTo(this.coll, 'reset', this.render);
  this.coll.fetch();              
},
render : function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template({ table: this.coll.toJSON() }));
  return this;
}

});
```

This is my template in index.html :

```
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    <script type="text/template" id="table-template">
      <ul> 
        <% _.each(table, function(table)  { %>
          <li><%= table.name %></li>
        <% }); %>
      </ul>
    </script>
```

data from json file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Table 1",
        "id": 1
    },

    {
        "name": "Table 2",
        "id": 2
    },

    {
        "name": "Table 3",
        "id": 3
    },

    {
        "name": "Table 4",
        "id": 4
    }

]
```

Please help me.... I don't know where is fault or what is missing.

Comment: What is the exception you get??

Comment: data from my json ....[
        {
            "name": "Table 1",
            "id": 1
        },
        
        {
            "name": "Table 2",
            "id": 2
        },

        {
            "name": "Table 3",
            "id": 3
        },
        
        {
            "name": "Table 4",
            "id": 4
        },
        
        {
            "name": "Table 5",
            "id": 5
        },

        {
            "name": "Table 6",
            "id": 6
        }

]

Comment: @MatejMarko none of the code you posted references TablesView, only defines it, so that error is coming from something else. Can you include the code where you reference TablesView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using [Backbone.Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) plugin, which supports rendering of lists out of the box. You don't have to write boilerplate code for it. Just use `CollectionView` or `CompositeView` with the collection given as constructor arguments and define an `ItemView` for them (li element)

Comment: you are right, I am using the same and found it is the great use.

Comment: we need the code where You reference TablesView and try to instantiate it

Comment: I have done this part of code ...you can see there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318576/backbonejs-pass-data-from-one-to-other-view
anyway thanks for help