# Backbonejs pass data from one to other view?

Tags: json, backbone.js

There I have two views ... I need put data from one view to next but I dont know how can I implement this .

There Is first function view :

```
var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize:function () {
    this.render();
},
render:function () {
    var that = this;
    var categories = new Categories();
    categories.fetch({
        success: function (categories) {
        var template = _.template($('#categories-template').html(), {categories: categories.models});
          that.$el.html(template);
        }
    })
}             
});
```

There is template :

```
    <script type="text/template" id="categories-template">
        <% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>
            <li><%= category.get('name') %></li> 
        <% }); %>
    </script>
```

Model and collection :

```
var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    name: 'Category',
    id: []
},
});
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: 'api/categories.json'
});
```

All names from json objects (all category) I have in :

```
<li>there</li>
```

...To each category I need implement Products .... there I have list of products :

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize:function () {
    this.render();
},
render:function () {
    var that = this;
    var products = new Products();
    products.fetch({
        success: function (menus) {
        var template = _.template($('#products-template').html(), {products: products.models});
          that.$el.html(template);
        }
    })
}             
});
```

Template :

```
    <script type="text/template" id="products-template">
        <% _.each(products, function(product) { %>
                <li class="productscls"><%= product.get('name') %></li> 
        <% }); %>
    </script>
```

Model and coollection:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    name: 'Product',
    category: 1,
    id: []
},
});
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: 'api/products.json'
});
```

All this my stuff is showed correct but when I try to make something like there :

```
    <script type="text/template" id="categories-template">
        <% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>
                <li class="categorycls"><%= category.get('name') %></li>
            <% _.each(products, function(product) { %>
                    <li class="productscls"><%= product.get('name') %></li>
            <% }); %>
        <% }); %>
    </script>
```

So there you can see what I wanna make. For each category each product but this not function without passing data into category or products view....

Regards Makromat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will want to do a parent wrapper view around the Category and Product views, which are then subviews. I would also do my fetching in the initialize methods, not in the renders. I think what you could do is use the Category view to render an element that has all the categories with placeholders for each Product by Id. Then use that as a template for the Product view, iterate each Product and insert it in the matching (by Id) Category placeholder element. That could work. Pretty complex stuff. Does this make sense at all?

Another idea might be a database view that "flattens" this relationship. Then use one BB view with a collection based on that database view.

2nd idea might be tough with not knowing how many products are within the categories. First idea will definitely work. Build a template that has every Category with Id marked placeholders, then pass that as the template to Product view, insert the list of Products at each Category Id placeholder.

Comment: Locohost Thanks for answer!!! I thinking about this solution gist.github.com/makromat/6291554 Have some experience somebody ?

Comment: @MatejMarko: Ok nesting.js looks pretty great. I think that may be a better solution than mine. I can use this too :-)